# How to recursively rename all files and folder including specific part of the filename with Windows Bash?

Tags: windows, bash, rename

This *has* to be a **duplicate** but I have read and tried at least a dozen of Q&As here on SO, and I cannot get any of them working for my case.

*Really hope this won't result in downvotes because of it.*

So I'm on Windows (10) and have a Bash terminal that I want to use for my task. The MINGW64 one I downloaded when I started working with Git.

[image: Git Bash]

I would prefer the solution with this program, but will be perfectly happy with one in Command Prompt Terminal or even PowerShell.

I created a `TemplateApp` which is in `C:\Apps\TemplateApp` folder which has multiple folders and subfolders named `TemplateApp` or `TemplateApp.something` as well as a lot of files that have `TemplateApp` as a part of their name.

Could be:

- `TemplateApp.ext`
- `TemplateApp.something.ext`
- `something.TemplateApp.something.ext`

Then I copied the uppermost folder to `C:\Apps\TemplateApp - Copy` and in turn renamed it to `C:\Apps\ProductionApplication`.

Now for the love of whomever, I cannot make any of the scripts I found on SO to work for my case, ie. to rename all the above mentioned files and folders by replacing `TemplateApp` with `ProductionApplication`.

Comment: you meant windows **batch**, didn't you?

Comment: @Kent Question edited. I didn't, but as I have said now, that would be perfectly OK as well. Please correct me if Git Bash is not the appropriate name for terminal in the image.

Comment: I know git for windows brings a git bash. I have no experience with it, cannot tell the difference between it and bash. But I think your **"windows bash"** in this situation makes sense, though the combination looks a bit strange. sorry.

Comment: @Kent That's quite alright. As I've said, I'm happy with any working solution (be it GitBash, CMD or PS), as long as I can readily use it in my case without overwritting what shouldn't be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash function I wrote that I think does very much like what you are wanting to do.

```
function func_CreateSourceAndDestination() { 
# 
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#files_syncSource[@]} ; i++ )) ; do 
    files_syncDestination[${i}]="${files_syncSource[${i}]#${directory_MusicLibraryRoot_source}}"        
    file_destinationPath="$( dirname -- "${directory_PMPRoot_destination}${files_syncDestination[${i}]}" )" 
    if [ ! -d "${file_destinationPath}" ] ; then 
        mkdir -p "${file_destinationPath}" 
    fi 
    rsync -rltDvPmz "${files_syncSource[${i}]}" "${directory_PMPRoot_destination}${files_syncDestination[${i}]}" 
done 
}
```

In my case I'm feeding into rsync for a source and a destination.  I'm pulling all the file paths from an array that has been split into path segments.  I have to make certain character substitutions for FAT and NTFS file systems.  I do this recursively.

```
files_syncDestination[${i}]="${files_syncDestination[${i}]//\:/__}"
```

That's the magic.  I load a new array with the character substituted.  You could do the same with a loaded variable including your phrases for change.

```
files_syncDestination[${i}]="${files_syncDestination[${i}]//${targetPhrase}/${subPhrase}}"
```

After that change in the function, you could use rsync or cp or mv as you prefer to go from your source array to your destination array.

(The double-slash in the substitution makes the substitution global.)

Comment: Now that looks very cryptic to my unknowledgeable self. 1. Can I use this to directly copy the uppermost folder `TemplateApp` to `ProductionApplication` without `Ctrl+C Ctrl+V`? 2. I don't get where to put `${targetPhrase}` and `${subPhrase}` in, where I suppose they are `TemplateApp` and `ProductionApplication` respectively. 3. What does it mean the substitution is global? Will it change the names in the original `TemplateApp` as well or does it just mean it's something like recursive inside the folder. 4. Do I have to be in `C:\Apps\ProductionApplication` before I run this? TYVM

Comment: targetPhrase="TemplateApp" 
subPhrase="ProductionApplication" 

if that's how you really plan to name them.  Those two declarations would come somewhere prior to this function being called in a script.  Or you could make those declarations at the top of the this same function, though you may want to get that data from the user running the script.  

A global substitution applies to all instances of the subPhrase within the array-line being evaluated.  

If you use rsync or mv or cp to make a second file with the substituted name, none of these will change the source file (path) names.

Comment: These instructions should allow you to set bash fully up on Win10:  http://jamesisin.com/a_high-tech_blech/

Comment: OK, so I went in the `C:\Apps\ProductionApplication` folder in `Windows Explorer`, right-clicked the empty space and selected `Git Bash Here`. I copied `targetPhrase="TemplateApp"` and  `subPhrase="ProductionApplication"` to the opened terminal and pressed `Enter` after each. Then I copied the entire function posted above as is and pressed `Enter`. Then I also typed in `func_CreateSourceAndDestination()` and `Enter` again. Nothing changed. I'm too dumb... Sorry to disappoint. Edit: it didn't even execute the function on last command. Just went to a new line with `> ` at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you have not ever written your own script.  This function would sit inside of a script that took user input to fill the two variables in question (though those could be hard-coded into the script as well).  I won't have time to write the script for you, but you can see this function in my PMPSync.sh script:  https://github.com/jamesisin/blech

Comment: I'm sorry to say I haven't. I suppose I would manage to craft my own solution from the existing answers on SO, if I had. If anyone else has the time and knowledge to do what I need, I would appreciate it immensely. I will of course upvote both answers as well and accept the working one.

Comment: Sounds like this might make you a great first script.  Low risk; high reward!  Bash is fun to get into because you can automate just this sort of thing pretty easily (though while you are slogging through work it can be frustrating until you break through).

Comment: One thing I can offer is my bash template:  https://github.com/jamesisin/blech/blob/master/TemplateBash.sh